# I cant update my product short description?

Tags: product, short

I'm trying to update the short description of a product in the full edition way in woocommerce  but if I save it, appears the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

deactivate all plugins and try again ... if it works activate the plugins one by one, always checking if it still works